# Question about a set of first category dense

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$ with $E_n=(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{j=1}^{2^{k-1}}A^n_{kj})^C$,
$\mu (A^n_{kj})=\frac{\lambda_k}{n}$ with $\lambda_k < 3^{-k}$,$E_n$ is a Cantor set

If I prove that $\mu(E)=1$  then I have given an example of a set of first category and dense?

Comment: *I have given an example of a set of first category and dense* --- If this is all you want, why not just use ${\mathbb Q}$?

Comment: Because the professor suggested to us to use this set